# Catalog price rules disappear after night with flat options

Tags: magento-1.9

I have activated the flat category and flat product option and furthermore i have activated different cataloge price rules.

After the night my special prices are not shown anymore even when i clicked on "apply rules". I need to disable flat options and apply the rules and then activate flat options with reindex.

So how could i fix that? I just want to keep all rules everyday and reindex myself when doing changes for some products.